# List of collocations in English

Tags: english, resource-request, online-resources, collocations

Does anybody know of source (probably NLP study) of comprehensive list of collocations in English (not only the frequent one). Additionally, does anybody know the approximate estimate of the total number of collocations.

Comment: I'm one of a number of people on this list who are not experts.  Could you please expand your answer, starting with an explanation of what a "collocation" is in this context.

Comment: This was cross-posted on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122699/list-of-collocations-in-english).

Comment: Those who want to follow this question might want to check out the Wikipedia article on collocations here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation.  //   Also, for Ross's benefit, there is a dictionary of English collocations available for purchase.  Check out this page:   http://www.macmillandictionaries.com/features/how-dictionaries-are-written/macmillan-collocations-dictionary/

Comment: I am aware of  and have worked extensively with five English collocations dictionaries (Longman http://collocations.longmandictionariesonline.com/, OUP, Macmillan, BBI http://benjamins.com/#catalog/books/z.bbi/main, and LTP). Not sure if this is what you're looking for. You could make your own list, too.

Comment: Also, take a look at http://www.collocates.info/

Comment: Alex, thanks for the link. I know this site but seems I have forgotten it since I visited it long time ago :)

Answer (score 3):

A great place to start is http://www.collocates.info which is based on COCA (Corpus of Contemporary American English). It is incredibly comprehensive (not free but the prices range from $45-$250).

This site also answers the question as to how many collocates there are in English? 4.3 million. That is from the perspective of all possible collocate relationships (even incredibly weak ones). You can only ask that question meaningfully if you have a purpose in mind. For instance, collocates to help students learn. Collocates that should trigger text autocomplete. Etc.

If you're looking for collocations for students, then you can start with the [Oxford Collocations Dictionary](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194325385) which lists 250k collocations.

Or you can use the [free online collocations dictionary](http://prowritingaid.com/Free-Online-Collocations-Dictionary.aspx). But you can only search that, not browse the whole list.

For NLP purposes, your best source is COCA or the already mentioned Google Ngrams (which has many limitations, also mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

You can download Google Ngrams whole dataset.

http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

Comment: Unfortunately, n-grams are not collocations, but collocations are n-grams.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Isn't there some way to extract the information you want out of the n-gram dataset?

Comment: Collocations are subset of n-grams. I already work with Google Ngrams. That is why I am looking for NLP study that already have extracted collocations.